# Log-binomial regression for binary outcome with multiple category predictors and numeric predictors

Tags: r

I'm trying to get RR from log-binomial regression with binary outcome. There are two categorical variables: treatment and group, two numeric variables: age and BMI.
But I get an error
***Error: cannot find valid starting values: please specify some.*** May I ask how can I fix this error?

```
N <- 50
data.1 <- data.frame(Outcome=sample(c(0, 0, 1), N, rep=T), Age=runif(N, 8, 58),
                     BMI=rnorm(N, 25, 6), Group=rep(c(0, 1), length.out=N),
                     treatment=rep(c('1', '2', '3'), length.out=N))
data.1$Group <- as.factor(data.1$Group)
coefini <- exp(coef(glm(Outcome ~ Group + treatment + Age + BMI, data=data.1, 
                        family=binomial(link="logit"))))
fit2 <- glm(Outcome ~ Group + treatment + Age + BMI, data=data.1, 
            family=binomial(link="log"), start=coefini)
```

Comment: for what it's worth this example works fine if you leave out `start` (i.e. the default starting values are OK)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be because the coefficients from logistic regression don't work for the log binomial regression. Replace the third line with `coefini=coef(glm(Outcome~Group+treatment+Age+BMI, data=data.1,family =binomial(link = "log") ))` and it works. (Remove the `exp` and change the link to `log`.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but it doesn't work and there is an `Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values.`

Comment: `set.seed(200)` and `set.seed(2000000)` both work for me. But certain seeds cause that error message. Do they work for you, using the replacement third line in my post?

Comment: As long as I use more than one categorical variable (Group, treatment ) in model with `family =binomial(link = "log") `, it returns an `Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values.` But it works when I only use Group in model. Weird.

Comment: Anyway..I asked my friend to run these code on her PC and the code works well...I will check my software...Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic coefficients can produce a positive linear combination, which in log-binomial regression means P(success) > 1. It looks like R returns this Error when that happens. Finding starting values that don't lead to that situation can be challenging.

A question/answer in [another community](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Statistical-Procedures/starting-point-in-the-PROC-GENMOD/td-p/13049) was useful to me in computing starting values for log-binomial regression.

That question is about the starting values for LOGISTIC regression, and its answer is that "you can get them using [linear regression] by regressing the logit of the response, y, on the predictors with weight ny(1-y)"

In that question, the binary (1/0) dependent variable is REMISS. And the answer provides these steps to obtain starting values for a logistic regression:

```
y=.1*(remiss=0)+.9*(remiss=1)
logit=log(y/(1-y))
wt=y*(1-y)
```

Then the starting values come from the weighted linear regression of LOGIT with the predictors of interest.

But I adjusted a couple of things for link="log" instead of "logit": Instead of

```
logit = log(y/(1-y))
wt = y*(1-y)
```

I used

```
depvar = log(y)
wt = y/(1-y)
```

Then the starting values for the log-binomial model are the results of the weighted linear regression of depvar with the same predictors.

I am more into Python than R these days, but I believe with your example, that means the following:

```
data.1['y'] <- 0.1 * (data.1['Outcome']==0) + 0.9 * (data.1['Outcome']==1)
data.1['depvar'] <- log(data.1['y'])
data.1['wt'] <- data.1['y'] / (1 - data.1['y'])
coefini <- coef(glm(formula = depvar ~ Group + treatment + Age + BMI, weights=wt, data = data.1))
fit2 <- glm(Outcome ~ Group + treatment + Age + BMI, data=data.1, 
            family=binomial(link="log"), start=coefini)
```