# can't fit GLM with family binomial and log link to estimate RR

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I am trying to estimate relative risk using log-binomial model using the glm function. Although it works well with univariable analysis, it gives me an error message when I add multiple variables

This is the error message I get
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values.

I did some search but couldn't find a way to solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: can you give us a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: There are a couple of similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322811/log-binomial-regression-in-r-not-working-for-me) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593141/log-binomial-regression-for-binary-outcome-with-multiple-category-predictors-and) that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen for one of two reasons. First, if any of the deviances are infinite, and second, if invalid starting values have been supplied. Assuming that you haven't supplied starting values, then I suggest doing so, by using the `start =`  option in `glm`.

Having said that, the only times I have seen this problem is when either the dataset is pathological, or the model is wrong (for example using an inappropriate link function). Since you don't supply a reproducible example, there isn't much more we can say.